# Combination/Permutation Dilemma

Tags: simulation, group-differences, combinatorics

This is probably quite a straight forward one - but still struggling to get my head around it.

To explain my problem:
In my work, I'm trying to put subjects into groups of 4 for a second round of an experiment based on their test scores in the first round (n = 20), therefore 5 groups in total.

There are 20 C 4 ways of combining the individuals into groups of size 4 = 4845 possible different groups. What I want to know is how many *unique* combinations are possible of 5 different groups of 4, given that individuals are free to vary within each.

The applied purpose of this is that I am writing a code that allocates individuals into groups so as to minimise the between groups mean and variances, so need to know how many iterations to let the simulation run through.

To embark on a total digression, upon writing this post title I also discovered 'dilemma' is not in fact spelled 'dilemna' (as is apparently also widely believed by many) so am already 1 up today.

Answer (score 1):

Denote the groups 1,2,3,4,5. First we pick 4 individuals for group 1. That gives $\binom{20}{4}$ ways. Now we pick 4 individuals for group 2: $\binom{16}{4}$. For group 3: $\binom{12}{4}$. This gives:

$$\binom{20}{4}\binom{16}{4}\binom{12}{4}\binom{8}{4}\binom{4}{4}=\frac{20!}{4!^5}.$$

However this doesn't take into account multiplicity, so it depends on what you're asking. In the above formulation each group is different. So if Alice, Bob, Sam and Jenny go into group 1, that would be a different combination then if Alice, Bob, Sam and Jenny go into group 4. If you'd like to *not* distinguish between group numbers, you'll need to divide by an extra $4!$ to account for the group orderings. In the latter interpretation, the only thing that matters is that Alice, Bob, Sam and Jenny are in the same group, regardless of it's number.

Comment: Thanks both for the answers, this caused slightly more debate in our lab than was perhaps warranted, but in the end we've come to a slightly different answer:

Picking 4 individuals for group 1, then 4 for group 2, 4 for group 3 etc..

$${20 \choose 4} + {16 \choose 4} + {12 \choose 4} + {8 \choose 4} + {4 \choose 4} = 7231$$

Then dividing by 5! to remove any additional complexity arising from the ordering of the groups, which is $7231/5! = 60$

Comment: @Nigel_Slater's_Carrot: I read your question again, and I've added some more details. My original answer assumes that groups 1,2,3,4 are all different. If you don't account for this difference, you'll get the other answer.

Answer (score 1):

One approach: 20! ways to order the people. But the order within each group doesn't matter; so divide by $4!^5$. Finally, the order of the groups doesn't matter, so divide by 5!.

The answer is then $\frac{20!}{5!4!^5} = 2546168625$.

To divide $n*k$ people into $n$ groups of $k$ is then $\frac{(n*k)!}{n!k!^n}$.

(Compared to the approach/assumptions [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/266527); if one finishes by saying that the five groups are indistinguishable one divides by 5! and the same result is achieved.)